# universal property of Albanese variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, projective-varieties

Where can I find proof for the universal property of Albanese variety?

(**The universal property of the Albanese variety**): For any (smooth projective) variety $X$ over a field $k$, there exists an abelian variety $Alb(X)$ and a morphism $\alpha: X → Alb(X)$ with the following universal property: for any abelian variety $T$ and any morphism $f : X → T$, there exists a unique morphism (up to translation) $ \tilde{f}: A → T$ such that $\tilde{f} \circ α = f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the definition of the Albanese variety. Presumably you mean something like why the dual of $\mathrm{Pic}^0$ is the Albanese variety in good situations? I've always liked the appendix to [this](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/Topics%20in%20Absolute%20Anabelian%20Geometry%20I.pdf) paper of Mochizuki's. In particular, take a look at Proposition A.6.

Comment: Well, here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/02-245/sclass18A.pdf says it is a theorem. I would like to see the proof, just. I think I'm looking for something simpler than your answer.

Comment: @Manoel I think you're confused. In your cited article Vakil is stating a theorem of the existence of some abliean variety $\mathrm{Alb}(X)$, as you stated above. He then defines the Albanese variety to be an abelian variety that satisfies the universal property in the theorem. So, yes, by definition the Albanese variety satisfies that universal property (responding to yoru title). The actual question is you're asking why it exists. I told you that at least for nice $X$ (e.g. the $X$ in the version of the Theorem you state--smooth projective) you can use the dual abelian variety to

Comment: $\mathrm{Pic}^0{X/k}$. This is proved in the article I linked you to. As Vakil says, it is a hard theorem insofar as you need a non-trivial amount of background. If you're working over $\mathbb{C}$ there are ways to 'cheat' by explicitly defining it as a complex vector space modulo a lattice, but this itself still needs some minor Hodge theory. Anyways, you explicitly stated $k$ to be a general field in your question, which is why I didn't mention this fact. Regardless, it sounds like from your own answer that you're happy with what you found, and that's all that matters. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For a proof see: A. Beauvile *Complex Algebraic Surface*, Theorem V.13, page 61.